# How to extract vector from 3d numpy array?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, covariance

I have a set of numpy.arrays of NXM (two dimensions: Range and Azimuth). 
I need to form a stack of three dimensions and extract a single dimension vector to compute a covariance matrix (the red vectors in the picture).

[image]

How i do this efficiently and easy in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a 3D numpy array pretty easily and then just use the indexing to pull out the bits that you're interested in:

```
stackOfImages = np.array((image1, image2)) #iterate over these if many more
redData = stackOfImages[:, N-1, M-1]
```

Comment: At this moment I have 2D numpy arrays. I need to form a 3D numpy array to do what you say? With hstack?

Comment: Sorry I completely misread, hopefully this answers your question now.

Comment: How I can iterate over "k" 2D numpy arrays to create a parametrized stackOfImages efficiently an pythonicly?:
stackOfImages = np.array((image1, image2)) #iterate over these if many more

Comment: @eduardosufan: To stack a collection of (identically-shaped) 2d arrays into a 3d array, you can either use [`numpy.dstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html), or in NumPy 1.10 and later, [`numpy.stack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html).

Comment: @ncfirth How can I do to avoid/improve the two fors to index N and M over stackOfImages? Maybe using flat or something in 1 dimension.

Comment: @eduardosufan I don't understand why you would want to construct a 3D array if don't want to use the indexing. Please give a use case.